# return domain name in javascript

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use javascript to echo/return the domain name into a displayed document.
I found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_domain) code that works by using a button click

But I need it to run automatically when the page is loaded.
The idea is so I have an about page on a site with multiple domains.
So if someone loads foo.com the page says "About FOO.COM" and if someone loads BAR.COM it likewise says "About BAR.COM" on the fly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to return the domain name of the server that loaded this document.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=document.domain;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show us your code. You can display domain name also using PHP and if you use PHP it will possible be the better solution

Comment: You should go and actually learn JavaScript

Comment: The code in given link is JavaScript. Java and JavaScript are two different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function immediately instead of putting it in an event handler.

```
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
<div id="yourbutton>your Button</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yourbutton").html(document.domain);
});
</script>
```

without jquery:
search for window.onload

...yay my first post on stackoverflow ;